# What does $(@:.h=.h.d) mean in GNU make?

Tags: makefile

I'm maintaining a (horrendously complicated) Makefile, and in some recipes I saw the following:

```
$(@:.h=.h.d)
```

I have absolutely no clue as to how to interpret this, or whether there's any documentation on those characters. Obviously, Google won't work because it thinks I'm typing gibberish.

I saw a related question about `@:H`, but this is GNU make instead of BSD make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [variable reference with a substitution](https://gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html#Substitution-Refs): `$(VAR:FROM=TO)`. It means the value of the variable `VAR`, but for each whitespace-separated word in the value, if the word ends with the suffix `FROM`, it is replaced by the suffix `TO`.

In this case, the variable is `@`, the [filename of the target of the rule](https://gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables) (with special handling for archive members). If the target of the rule ends with `.h`, then `.d` is added at the end.

A common file naming convention is to use `.d` for a list of dependencies. The file `foo.h.d` presumably contains dependencies for rules to compile source files that include `foo.h` (so, in practice, `foo.d.h` would contains `foo.h` and the headers that it includes).

By the way, this is portable syntax. There is another slightly more wordy syntax which is common (supported by both GNU and BSD make) but not POSIX: `$(@:%.h=%.h.d)` where the `%` acts as a wildcard; this syntax allows a prefix to be substituted in addition to a suffix. There is yet another syntax to do the same thing in GNU make: [call](https://gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Syntax-of-Functions.html#Syntax-of-Functions) the function [`patsubst`](https://gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-patsubst-1), written `$(patsubst %.h,%.h.d,$@)` — it's arguably less cryptic, but because the portable syntax has existed for decades, it's commonly used even in makefiles that otherwise require GNU make.

Comment: Jesus, that's insane. Good thing I'm not a Perl programmer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @reinierpost But in this case, finding the right part of the manual isn't easy.